# Chrome switch n tabs right/left

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

I navigate between tabs using shortcuts to switch to the right/left tab (ctrl-(shift)-tab). It can take a lot of strokes if the target tab is quite far.

Any shortcut/extension/script to skip n tabs when switching? Or any other concepts of tabs switching? Maybe switching to the middle/quoter tab?

Search tabs by name isn't a good option for me. Sometimes I don't know tab name, only know that desired tab was "about 10 tabs" before current.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Number will bring you to the tab corresponding to the number.

I.e. Ctrl + 6 will bring you to the 6th tab from the left.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> to jump one tab to the right, and use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> to jump one tab to the left. On Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next tab to the right and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next tab to the left.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. It is generally discouraged to answer very old questions unless you're actually adding something  substantive to what has already been answered.  Your answer is low value.  You did not carefully read the question asked and are not answering the specific question. It is also a duplicate of an [existing low value answer](https://superuser.com/a/1750131/).  I recommend you voluntarily delete it so that it doesn't reflect poorly on you as you continue to be a part SuperUser

Answer (score -1):

The current versions of chrome have a shortcut to switch to the left/right tab

On Mac:

`Command (⌘) + Option (⌥) + Left/Right key`

On Windows I'm assuming it should be `Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right key`

Comment: They want to switch **n** tabs within a single action.